# How do you get LibreOffice to close via automation after opening it?

Tags: delphi, ole, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to open LibreOffice Calc and then close it again using ole automation.

The problem is that although I can open the spreadsheet, when I try to close it, only the spreadsheet window closes, the soffice processes remain in the task manager, so LibreOffice wasn't properly closed.

Here is the Delphi code which I use to open a spreadsheet:

```
Office: Variant;
frame: Variant;
Desktop: Variant;
comp: Variant;
Doc: Variant;
args: Variant;

Office := CreateOleObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
desktop := Office.CreateInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop');
args := VarArrayCreate([0,1], varVariant);
Doc := desktop.loadComponentFromURL('private:factory/scalc', '_blank', 0, args);
```

The spreadsheet is now open and everything seems fine, now I want to close it
so I tried this, which doesn't work properly:

```
  Doc.Dispose;
  frame := Desktop.FindFrame('_blank', 0);
  frame.Dispose;
  Desktop.Dispose;
  Office.Dispose;
```

I also tried this which also doesn't work properly:

```
  Doc.Close(True);
  sleep(500);
  Desktop.Dispose;
  Office.Dispose;
```

In both cases the program window closes, but the soffice processes remain in the task manager.
This was tested with LibreOffice 6 on Windows 7.

I did find this which is supposed to work:

```
xModifiable = (XModifiable)xComponent;
xModifiable.setModified(false);
xCloseable = (XCloseable)xComponent;
xCloseable.close(true);

// This closes all instances, even ones you didn't create
// If you don't write this, you'll find 'soffice.bin' still lingering in taskmgr
XDesktop xDesktop = (XDesktop)xCLoader;
if(xDesktop != null)
        xDesktop.terminate();
```

But I can't compile that in Delphi.

Comment: Welcome! Please see [**Delphi 7 OOo tool**](https://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/Files_en/Delphi_OOo_v14en.zip). [**Bernard Marcelly**](https://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html) wrote this library when LibreOffice didn't exist yet. I have used this, it works. You will need the `DisconnectOpenOffice(True);` (this is on page 7/27 of the description of the *Annexes/OOo_COM_Delphi_v12en.odt library*)

Comment: @JohnSUN  Thank you very much.  Embarrassingly I had already found the solution, but somehow turned "terminate" into "dispose".  Reading your reference made me realise my mistake.  I must be getting too old for this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in this example is `Desktop.Terminate`.  This causes LibreOffice to close and its processes to terminate, though any modified documents should be closed prior to that.
However, according to "doug" in a post on ask.libreoffice.org dated 2015:

> To create a clean shutdown, that does not later prompt for file
> recovery, a substantial Wait appears necessary prior to the terminate
> command because of an apparent race condition in LibreOffice.  Your
> Wait may need to be longer, or it might be shorter. Thus the sequence
> ending with the clean terminate command would be:

```
Doc.Close(True);
Sleep(400);
Desktop.Terminate;
```

> Called by itself, the terminate command does generate a save prompt if
> the current document is modified, but the shutdown typically will be
> unclean due to the noted race condition.

[code modified to suit the example in the question]